# Marker Not showing Info-window in Angular google map

Tags: angular, google-maps-markers, infowindow, agm

i am using agm version 1.0.0

```
 <agm-map class="plant-portfolio-map" [center]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="12" [disableDefaultUI]="false"
  [zoomControl]="true" (mapClick)="mapClick($event)" [mapTypeId]="'satellite'">
  <agm-marker *ngFor="let m of markers; let i = index" [markerClickable]="true" (markerClick)="onMarkerClick(m)"
    [latitude]="m.lat" [longitude]="m.lng" [markerDraggable]="m.draggable">
    <agm-info-window [isOpen]="true">
      <strong>
        Latitude: {{m.lat}}, Longitude: {{m.lng}}, Altitude:
        {{m.altitude}}
      </strong>
    </agm-info-window>
  </agm-marker>

  <agm-overlay [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"
    [bounds]="{x:{latitude:-0.003,longitude:-0.0052},y:{latitude:0.003,longitude:0.0052}}">

    <div style="width:15px;height:15px;background-color:blue;"></div>
  </agm-overlay>
</agm-map>
```

this my code for agm-map.but  markeclick not working and also info-window not show any data.i have multiple marker and want t o show popup on hover on marker.

please give solution that show info-window on hover on marker.